# put user details in session in spring-security.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following spring-security.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
           <intercept-url pattern="/ADMIN/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
           <form-login default-target-url="/" login-page="/login.jsp" />
           <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
           <authentication-provider>
             <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
               users-by-username-query="select user_name,password, enabled from Users where user_name=?"  
               authorities-by-username-query="select u.user_name, u.role from Users u where u.user_name =?"/>                 
           </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

How to put user details in session like username and user_id etc. after user login to website.

Answer (score 0):

Once you logged in there already is a security context in the Session & ThreadLocal. You can call it like this:

```
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext()...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve username of logged-in user. Then you can use username to retrieve user specific information from database.

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
String userName = userDetails.getUsername();
```

Or you can always use HttpSession object to store attributes in session.

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String myControllerMethod(HttpSession session) {
    session.addAttribute("username", "test123");
}
```

you can also use HttpServletRequest object to store attributes in session.

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String myControllerMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("userName", "test123");
}
```